# How to compensate for unequal sample sizes in multivariate tests?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, sample-size, manova, permutation-test

I have several linear and geometric cranial variables of specimens sampled from about 20 different localities. The sample sizes per locality range between 9 – 100. What would be the best multivariate statistical tests for this dataset to compensate for the unequal sample sizes?

Comment: You have not indicated  the population size or any other relevant characteristics  of localities  ?  and no statement of your problem you intend to solve.

Comment: Sample size/population per each locality vary between 9 and 100. These were geographically separated groups by water bodies, extensive dryland divides, mountainous breaks, ... My aim is to test whether geographic structuring has imparted some form of local cranial variation and whether there is an underlying pattern in such variation if any.

Comment: How many cranial variables ?  name of each variable and measurements, nature of data.Incorporate part of data/output etc in your question ?